# EmberJS - Clearing form fields on child component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on a project which has a component that's generating custom fields for forms, in which I need to reset their content once a button is pressed. This button also resets the rest of the hard coded fields.

```
{{#custom-form fields=fields}}
```

This is how I'm passing the data to generate the fields to the child component, and the inputs are generated through a regular {{#each fields as |field|}}. Another component generates the fields themselves, like so:

```
{{input value=field.value placeholder=field.name}}
```

How can I access these generated fields to reset them at the same time the rest of the form is reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. See the implementation(working example) in the below link.

[Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/ebc6c4184955a3f8a6d76a556cd9f560?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.custom-form.hbs)

You need a separate component for the custom fields `custom-fields`. The function related to the custom fields are handled only in that component (Create, Read, Update). And also need a global mapping in the template, that passes the fields to the custom component, so that all fields will be cleared in a single click.

Implementation:

**application.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  fields:function()
  {
        return {defaultfields: [{name:"User ID",value:""},
                        {name:"Email",value:""},
                        {name:"Phone No.",value:""}],
              customfields: [{name:"Blood Group",value:""},
                         {name:"Gender",value:""},
                         {name:"Company",value:""}]};
  }.property(),
  actions:
  {
        clearAllFields:function()
        {
            var fields = this.get("fields");
            Object.keys(fields).forEach(function(key){
                        fields[key].setEach("value","");
          });
        }
  }
});
```

**application.hbs**

```
<h1>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
<br>
        {{#each fields.defaultfields as |field|}}
        {{input type="text" placeholder=field.name value=field.value}}<br>
    {{/each}}
    <br>
        {{custom-form fields=fields.customfields}}
    <br>
    <button {{action "submitData"}}>Submit</button>
    <button {{action "clearAllFields"}}>Clear All fields</button>
<br>
<br>
```

**custom-form.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  fields:"",
  isaddnewcustomproperty:false,
  actions:
  {
        toggleProperty : function(property)
        {
            this.toggleProperty(property);
      },
        addCustomProperty : function()
        {
            var fields = this.get("fields");
            var propname = this.get("propname");
            var propvalue = this.get("propvalue");
            var ispropertyabsent = fields.every(function(item){
                return item.name.toUpperCase() != propname.toUpperCase();
          });
            if(ispropertyabsent)
            {
                fields.pushObject({name:propname,value:propvalue});
            }
          else
          {
              var obj = fields.find(function(item){
                    return item.name.toUpperCase() == propname.toUpperCase();
              });
                Ember.set(obj,"value",propvalue);
                            Ember.setProperties(fields.find(function(item){ return item.name.toUpperCase() == propname.toUpperCase();}),obj);
          }
        },
        clearCustomFields : function()
        {
            this.get("fields").setEach("value","");
        }
  }
});
```

**custom-form.hbs**

```
{{#each fields as |field|}}
     {{input type="text" placeholder=field.name value=field.value}}<br>
{{/each}}

{{#if isaddnewcustomproperty}}
        {{input value=propname}}{{input value=propvalue}}
    <button {{action "addCustomProperty"}}>Add</button>
    <button {{action "toggleProperty" "isaddnewcustomproperty"}}>Cancel</button>
{{else}}
        <button {{action "toggleProperty" "isaddnewcustomproperty"}}>Add Field</button>
{{/if}}
<br>
<button {{action "clearCustomFields"}}>Clear custom fields</button>
```

Comment: Please include all the code in your answer, not just a link to your code

Comment: This worked perfectly. It's an implementation of Liam's suggestion, and it worked wonders. Thank you both

Comment: FYKI : I didn't referred to Liam's suggestion :). I just worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to loop through your `fields` and set `value` to null.